# Java - Getting integers out of a string

Tags: java, string, integer

Let us assume I have a string like this:

Class:class shapes_assignment.SquareX-Coordinate:314Y-Coordinate:50

How do I extract the two numbers out of it (that is, 314 and 50)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Matcher.matches()`:

```
String str = "Class:class shapes_assignment.SquareX-Coordinate:314Y-Coordinate:50";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\d+).*?(\\d+).*").matcher(str);
if (m.matches()) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
   System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
314
50
```

Answer (score 6):

**Use Regex:**

```
String s = "Class:class shapes_assignment.SquareX-Coordinate:314Y-Coordinate:50";
  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d)+");
  Matcher mat = pat.matcher(s);

  while(mat.find()){

   System.out.println(mat.group()); // You can store these numbers in variables
}
```

**You can use the below code to Convert and Store the numbers:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(mat.find()){

    System.out.println(mat.group());

    numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(mat.group()));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over every character of the String. If the character matches 0 - 9 then add it to a new string foo. Stop adding characters to this string when a character is not a number in consecutive order.

Once this is done, convert the string foo to an integer.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your string on non-digit characters:

```
String s = "Class:class shapes_assignment.SquareX-Coordinate:314Y-Coordinate:50"; 
String[] numbers = s.split("[^\\d]+");
```

Note that the first element will be an empty string if the input starts with non-digit characters.

You can then parse each non-empty string of the array with `Integer.parseInt()`.

Full working code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Class:class shapes_assignment.SquareX-Coordinate:314Y-Coordinate:50";
    String[] numbers = s.split("[^\\d]+");
    for (String number : numbers) {
        if (!number.isEmpty()) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt(number);
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
        }
    }
}
```